# How can I disable HTML validation for PHP files in Eclipse Juno 4.2.1?

Tags: php, html, eclipse, validation

I use Eclipse for PHP / MySQL / JS website development.  From Eclipse 4.2.1 Classic I’ve installed Data Tools Platform, Subclipse, and PDT.  Eclipse tries to do HTML validation on my PHP files, but gets confused with some of my jumping in and out of PHP, and certainly doesn’t like when my scripts output non-HTML XML.

In older versions of Eclipse (Ganymede maybe), I could go to Window > Preferences and turn off HTML validation in the Validators section, but I don’t have that section anymore.  I also don’t have it in project properties.

Ideally I just want HTML validation off for PHP, but since I don’t actually have any plain HTML files I’m fine with turning it off altogether.  The only answers I’ve found say to turn it off under Validators under Window > Preferences, but since that section isn’t there, that doesn’t help me.  Has it been renamed and moved, or is there something else I need to install to get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install "Eclipse Web Developer Tools" from juno repository.

Comment: Thanks!  Had to add `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/` and `http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/releases/` to get it to install, but now I have the validation section back and it’s no longer complaining about HTML in my PHP files.